# Является ли Python по сути высокоуровневым интерфейсом для C?

Tags: python, c

Насколько я понимаю, интерпретатор Python (в частности, PVM) — это просто программа, написанная на C, которая принимает на вход инструкции байт-кода и меняет свое состояние в зависимости от этих инструкций, но также может изменять среду, в которой она выполнялась, и ее элементы, такие как ОС или ее командная строка. Так что на самом деле Python — это просто фреймворк или что-то в этом роде, который предоставляет высокоуровневый интерфейс для вещей, которые можно сделать на чистом C, но гораздо сложнее реализовать. Все ли правильно я сказал? P.S. Это может быть глупый вопрос, но я просто пытаюсь сделать все как можно более понятным для себя :D

Comment: Ну, так можно любой язык рассматривать как высокоуровневый интерфейс для ассемблера/машинных команд...

Comment: 1) Python - язык программирования, так как он обладает свойствами ЯП. 2) От переопределения сущности не меняются, вряд ли станет что-то понятнее при этом. 3) Почему про компилятор Python тут ни слова не сказано? Возможно, надо с этого начать. 4) И @Harry уже написал то, что я ещё хотел заметить, но см. п.2.

Answer (score 5):

1. Интерпретатор Питона может быть написан на чём угодно. Самые популярные реализации Питона написаны действительно на `C` из-за его быстроты, однако есть версии, написанные на других языках, в частности и на самом Питоне (рекурсия? да).
2. Библиотеки Питона написаны в основном на `C`, но опять же не только на нём, часть числовых библиотек написана на современной версии `Fortran`, он работает с числами довольно быстро.
3. Питон - самостоятельный язык программирования, со своим синтаксисом и правилами, совершенно не похожий на `C`, поэтому в общем-то не сильно важно, на чём он интерпретатор написан, если вы просто на нём программируете и не лезете в глубокие детали реализации.

Comment: Но ведь самая популярная реализация написана на С... А на С++ вообще существуют реализации?

Comment: @user207200 Хм, наверное вы правы. Я что-то думал на чистом `C` уже никто и не пишет, но...

Comment: на чистом си писать проще чем на плюсах) многие интерпретаторы написанны именно на С без плюсов.

Comment: @eri Простите, но imho — cомнительное утверждение. Скорее на С больше потому, что он реально лет на 20 старше (да, я знаю, что *формально* — на 10 с небольшим), а не потому, что проще...

Comment: я написал 2 отдельных тезиса. это не причина и следствие

Comment: 4 пунктом я бы кое что добавил - питон написан на питоне

Python
65.5%
 
C
32.3%

Comment: @eri Спасибо за исправления. Может сделать ответ общим тогда лучше?

Comment: я ничего нового не добавил в исправлении. оставь как есть